# use dll for desktop application in asp.net core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-applications, agent

I want to communicate with an asp.net core web application via a dll for the .net framework with the desktop application PLCSIM Advanced (only installed on host) to enable control via another PC.
If the web application is started via Visual Studio in IIS Express, the communication works fine. If the web application is hosted via IIS on Windows 10 to allow access from other PCs, communication with PLCSIM Advanced will not work. It does not matter whether the application is started from the host PC or from another PC in the same network.

In my opinion, this is because IIS Express is running via the logged in user. If the web application is hosted via IIS, the desktop applications can no longer be accessed.

Is there a way to remove this separation or to somehow access the desktop application PLCSIM Advanced via the web application?

Comment: "Is there a way to remove this separation". Nope, you cannot disable Windows session isolation. Your only option is to rearchitect your components, so that some runs in a user session to communicate with PLCSIM Advanced.

Comment: Hi Lex Li, thanks for your answer. What do you mean with "rearchitect components" in detail?
Is there an option, to start PLCSIM in the same user session as the iis web application?